# How to prove that a function with certain properties is sigmoidal?

Tags: real-analysis

Okay so this is regarding the proof of the universal approximation theorem. So this is the theorem:

Let $ d \in \mathbb{N} $, let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d $ be compact, and let $\varrho \in L_{loc}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ be an activation function such that the closure of the points of discontinuity of $\varrho$ is a Lebesgue null set.
Further let
\begin{equation*}
  \tilde{ \mathcal{F}} = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}_{((d, n, 1), \varrho)}
 \end{equation*}
be the corresponding set of two-layer NN realizations. Then it holds that $C(K) \subset cl(\tilde{ \mathcal{F}})$ (where the closure is taken with respect to the topology induced by the $L^{\infty}(K)$ - norm) if and only if there does not exist a polynomial $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $p=\varrho$ almost everywhere.

The proof is basically showing a bunch of equivalences, where get in the end $C(K) \subset cl(\tilde{ \mathcal{F}})$ if and only if $\varrho$ is a sigmoidal function, but without any justification or explanation.
So my question is now if someone has an idea how to prove that $\varrho$ is a discriminatory function or even some ideas for a counterexample.
Note: $\varrho$ is a sigmoidal function, means
$ \varrho(x) = 1$ for $  x \rightarrow \infty $ $ \varrho(x) = 0$ for $  x \rightarrow -\infty$.
Thank you!

Comment: Where did I make a mistake?